# handling empty and spaces and null values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have small doubt in sql server.
My table emp contains data like

```
id, name
1,abc
2,
3,n
4,ja
5, jied
6,null
```

To replace null or empty with 9999 and avoid empty spaces I tried query like below

```
select coalesce(ltrim(rtrim(substring(name,1,5))) ,'') ='' then '9999' 
else substring(ltrim(rtrim(name),1,5) end name
FROM emp
```

I don't get a result but the following error is shown

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

Comment: You're doing more work than you need to - can you think of a single example of an input string where, following an `RTRIM()` it's got a non-zero length, but feeding that result into an `LTRIM()` will produce an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a few elements from your code: you need to add `CASE WHEN`, e.g.,

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN coalesce(ltrim(rtrim(substring(name,1,5))) ,'') ='' 
        THEN '9999' 
        ELSE substring(ltrim(rtrim(name)),1,5)
    END name
FROM emp
```

I'd also recommend you look into a couple of different approaches using the ISNULL and NULLIF functions.  For example, you could use `ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(name)), ''), '9999')`, which would take care of filtering out NULL values as well as blank values in a single statement.

EDIT: not knowing much about your data, I'm also a bit concerned about the fact that your two `SUBSTRING()` functions are doing different things.  In your WHEN clause, you run your `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` function against the five characters returned by the `SUBSTRING()` function, thereby theoretically returning less than five characters.  However, in your `ELSE` clause, you run the `SUBSTRING()` against the *already trimmed* result of name.

For examples, see the difference between the following two queries:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(' blank space here', 1, 5)))
SELECT SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(' blank space here')), 1, 5)
```

If you really need to limit this to the five characters, you should probably do your trimming on the name *before* you apply the `SUBSTRING()` function to it, i.e.,

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(Name)), 1,5), ''), '9999')
FROM  emp
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE WHEN` is missed and also missed `)` in **ELSE** part

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(name)),1,5) ,'') = '' THEN '9999' 
ELSE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(name)),1,5) END name
FROM emp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get '9999' when the name is null or empty, you can also use the following query instead, just another option apart from the above answers

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(name)),''),'9999') FROM emp
```